# asp.net mvc razor yes no dialog not coming in razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
  <%= Ajax.AjaxImageActionLink("../../Content/images/delete.png", "Feature", "Delete", new { id = item.int_FeatureId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "table", HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Delete Feature with Feature ID:" + item.int_FeatureId + " Feature Name:" + item.vcr_FeaturesName })%> pr
```

i am trying to generate javascript popup when pressing the delete link for yes and no. this works perfectly in .aspx views but how i can make it work in razor. i try to translate it but not working

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete Profile", "Delete", new { id = item.int_UserId }, new AjaxOptions {  UpdateTargetId = "UserTable", HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Delete User with User ID:" + item.int_UserId + " User Name:" + item.vcr_UserName })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite this in razor correctly and is not working, this is definitely not the case with aspx or razor. They're just parsers, and using any of them does not affect internal mvc code execution. Same on razor markup would be just remove aspx code end marker and replace start marker with '@'

```
  @Ajax.AjaxImageActionLink("../../Content/images/delete.png", "Feature", "Delete", new { id = item.int_FeatureId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "table", HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Delete Feature with Feature ID:" + item.int_FeatureId + " Feature Name:" + item.vcr_FeaturesName })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the following error and it seems to be something to do with the way the razor engine reads the jQuery function when you bundle or internally reference the scripts? I just referenced the files from the cdn and it works fine. This is the error you will likely get trying the former. Try referencing the jquery files from the cdn as this is probably your culprit.

[image: Chrome debugger]

Seems to work fine this way.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```